# How to update props of a Tab.Screen from Parent Component (passing a state value) , react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-props, react-navigation-top-tabs

My project Config :

```
{
   "expo" : "^45.0.0",
   "react-native": "0.68.2",
   "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
   "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
   "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
   "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
}
```

i'm using **TopTabNavigator** , to create four screens

```
const [dataStep1, setDataStep1] = useState({});
const [dataStep2, setDataStep2] = useState({});
const [dataStep3, setDataStep3] = useState({});

const step1Order = (dataInputs) =>
{
    if (dataInputs == null || dataInputs == {})
    {
        Alert.alert("Unknown Error", "Order Not Created , Please Check inputs you Entred");
        return;
    }

    setDataStep1(dataInputs);
}

// same above function for step2 & step3 step2Order() step3Order()


return (

<NavigationContainer>
   <Tab.Navigator>
       <Tab.Screen name="Step 1" component={Step1} initialParams={{ hundlerFillData: step1Order,}}/>
       <Tab.Screen name="Step 2" component={Step2} initialParams={{hundlerFillData: step2Order}} />
       <Tab.Screen name="Step 3" component={Step3} initialParams={{hundlerFillData: step3Order}} />
       <Tab.Screen name="Step 4" component={Step4} 
             initialParams={{
                  confirmOrder: step4Order,
                  dataOrder : {
                      dataStep1: dataStep1,
                      dataStep2: dataStep2,
                      dataStep3: dataStep3,
                  },
             }}
       />

    </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

**--> in the First 3 Steps (screens) i'm fill states using Callback functions "step#Order"**

> What i want is when i fill data in steps 1,2,3 i want the props of 'Screen 4' to be update automaticlly , i used states on **initialParams**, but it the screen component **does not re-rendred**

- this is how i declare screen 4 :

```
const Step4 = ({route, navigation}, props ) => {

    const {confirmOrder, dataOrder} = route?.params;

    useEffect(()=> {
        console.log("Step 4 Loaded ====  with dataOrder : \n", dataOrder);
    },[])

    /// Screen Focus
    useEffect(()=> {

        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            console.log("\n---- mini Hello in Focus Step 4 ----\n with props : \n", route.params);
        });
    
        return unsubscribe;
    }, [route]);


    return (
        <.../>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most commonly used way to do what you're describing is to use navigation params in the `navigate` call.  So, if you have all the data you need in screen 3, you'd call something like

`navigation.navigate('Screen4', { dataStep1, dataStep2, dataStep3 });`

And then in screen 4, since you're using hooks:

```js
const { params } = useRoute();
const { dataStep1, dataStep2, dataStep3 } = params || {};
```

Also, assuming you don't need the data anywhere else, you don't have to keep the state at the navigator level and pass callbacks to each screen.  You can just use navigation params as above to pass the data from one screen to the next.

```js
// screen 1
navigation.navigate('Screen2', { dataStep1 });

// screen 2
const { params } = useRoute();
const { dataStep1 } = params || {};
...
navigation.navigate('Screen3', { dataStep1, dataStep2 });
```

See [the params section of the React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/) for more.

Comment: to change the concept will solve the problem , but i will face another problem , and that's why i choose to put all my states in parent component . 

the problem i will face is , i should disable events of Clicking on Tab title to navigate to any screen , because if the user navigate from Screen1 to Screen4 that's will be a problem .

and i dont didn't find a way to disable that i event

Comment: this is how my Navigator looks like : 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gizPqShKIzFw_HjFWQBIoxwZmTOFdpGS/view?usp=sharing